# Razor, translations according to argument value

Tags: razor

I want to get translation according to provided argument.
For example I want to get translation for word 'Action'.

I can do it like:

```
@functions myFunction(string word) {
  string result;  

  switch (word) {
    case('Action'):  {
      result = @Globals.Action;
      break;
    }  

  return result;
}
```

and so on, but obviously this is very poor solution.

Is there any way of doing it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ResourceManager.GetString("Action", resourceCulture);
```

from selected `resource`